# Maximum number of UILocalNotification for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, uilocalnotification

Does any know the maximum number of  UILocalNotification supported by iphone OS ? Apple documentation talks about a maximum number of 64 but I wonder if that is for each application or for all applications together.

Documentation at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 5):

The limitation is per app.

Answer (score 3):

> Each application on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local
>   notifications. The system discards scheduled notifications in excess
>   of this limit, keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the
>   soonest. Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification.

[Check the Doc for more info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)

Comment: Updated link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification I had complications when more than 64 notifications, the system definitely did not keep the soonest ones.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in iOS 8.1 it is possible to schedule more than 64 notifications per app and all get fired. In my app I tested it with 500 and more local notifications and all get scheduled and fired on iPhone Simulator an on a real iPhone 5s. Maybe this is a bug in iOS 8.1 or Apple forgot to update the documentation.

Comment: I tested 1000 on local notifications. it's kinda slow but it works. thanks for pointing it out! :D

Answer (score 0):

Local notifications are primarily intended for apps with timer-based behaviors and simple calendar or to-do list apps. An app that is running in the background may also schedule a local notification to inform the user of an incoming message, chat, or update. An app can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and discards the rest.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html